# Part of string missing while concatenating 2 string variables

Tags: bash, concatenation

I am using Bash version 5.0.17 on Ubuntu.

I am trying to append a date and time (based on the file's modified date) to a filename for backup purposes.
I create the substring to append by doing the following:
(I am only showing literal strings here rather that the code for doing a "stat" on the filename since it is irrelevant here.)

```
iDate='2023-10-14'
iTime='1510'
```

With the above, if I re-assign the value of iDate using:

```
iDate="$iDate_$iTime"
```

...it yields the value of "1510" and not "2023-10-14_1510"

Why does this happen?
(I later changed it to iDate="$iDate"_"$iTime", and it gave the correct string)
Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$iDate_` is a valid variable name. Use something to separate the character from the variable name:

```
iDate="$iDate"_"$iTime"
iDate="$iDate\_$iTime"
iDate="${iDate}_$iTime"
```

Moreover, if you're just appending a value, you can use the `+=` operator in bash:

```
iDate+="_$iTime"
```

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot about the += operator. I could have done that.
If you say I have to escape the "\_" character with "\\_", why do I have to escape it? Are you saying that Bash interprets $iDate_ as a variable name?

Comment: Exactly. Try setting it to a value and see the result.

Comment: Underscore is a valid "identifier" character, along with letters and numbers. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-name